# Gensim: error loading pretrained vectors No such file or directory: 'word2vec.kv.vectors.npy'

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, gensim, embedding

I am trying to load a Pretrained word2vec embeddings that is in gensim keyedvector 'word2vec.kv'

```
pretrained = KeyedVectors.load(args.pretrained mmap = 'r')
```

where arg.pretrained is "/ptembs/word2vec.kv"
and iam getting this error

```
File "main.py", line 60, in main
pretrained = KeyedVectors.load(args.pretrained, mmap = 'r')
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1553, in load
model = super(WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 228, in load
return super(BaseKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 436, in load obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 478, in _load_specials
val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib), mmap_mode=mmap)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 417, in load
fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ptembs/word2vec.kv.vectors.npy'
```

i dont understand why it need word2vec.kv.vectors.npy file ? and i dont have it.
Any idea how to solve this problem?

---

gensim version 3.8.3
tried it on 4.1.2 also same error.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the file `'word2vec.kv'`?

If loading that file triggers an error mentioning a 2nd file by name, then that 2nd file should've been created alongside `'word2vec.kv'` when it was 1st saved using a `.save()` operation.

That other file needs to be kept alongside `'word2vec.kv'` in order for `'word2vec.kv'` to be `.load()`ed again in the future.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce results from the paper https://github.com/Law-AI/automatic-charge-identification so they have provided pre-trained embeddings and there is no mention of another file needed in the gensim load() method in its documentation.

Comment: I don’t see any `'word2vec.kv'`file downloadable at that Github project, so I’m still wondering, where did you get the file `'word2vec.kv'`? Still, also, if you try to `.load()` that file, & the error lists a specific 2nd filename that’s missing, that is because the 2nd file was originally created alongside `'word2vec.kv'`, & needed to be kept with it wherever it moved – but wasn’t. So you have to go to wherever `'word2vec.kv'` came from to get the file that is missing.

Comment: its present in ptemps folder in the same repository and loading of that file is in the main.py file at line number 59.

Comment: Ah, I now see `'ptembs/word2vec.kv'` in the project. But there's no `'ptembs/word2vec.kv.vectors.npy'` – which means that the author of that repository, Github user `shounakpaul95`, has not provided all the files required to load that model. To have any hope of loading `'ptembs/word2vec.kv'`, you need them to provide that file – so you'll have to ask them. (Alternatively, maybe they've provided enough info to re-train the model from raw data – in which case, after you save `'ptembs/word2vec.kv'`, you will see `'ptembs/word2vec.kv.vectors.npy'` alongside it – & maybe other necessary files too.)